# Why the total temperature remains constant through shock wave?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, aerodynamics, shock-waves

We know that total temperature is sum of static and dynamic temperature. If static temperature increases through the shock wave, then how total temperature remains constant? It must increase and not remain constant!

Similar question for total pressure reduction through shock wave while static pressure increases!

Answer (score 1):

Temperature and pressure *do not* remain constant through a shock wave. In fact, in shock waves, one can conserve mass, momentum, and energy to obtain three conservation equations:
$$\begin{align*}
\rho_1 v_1 &= \rho_2 v_2 = \Phi \\
p_1 + \rho_1 v_1^2 &= p_2 + \rho_2 v_2^2 \\
p_1 v_1 + \left(\rho_1 \tilde{u}_1 + \frac{1}{2}\rho_1 v_1^2\right)v_1 &= p_2 v_2 + \left(\rho_2 \tilde{u}_2 + \frac{1}{2}\rho_2 v_2^2\right)v_2
\end{align*}$$
These three conservation laws, collectively known as the [*Rankine-Hugoniot Conditions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine%E2%80%93Hugoniot_conditions) can be solved to express pressures on either side of the shock wave, or:
$$\frac{p_2}{p_1} = \frac{2\gamma M^2 - (\gamma - 1)}{\gamma + 1}$$
where $M = \frac{\rho_1 v_1^2}{\gamma p_1}$ is the Mach number and $\gamma$ is the adiabatic index. In the ideal gas approximation, this implies
$$\frac{T_2}{T_1} = \frac{p_2/\rho_2}{p_1/\rho_1}.$$